# copy specific value from text1 to text2 by dos

Tags: batch-file, command, dos

I need help to copy a specific value from `text1` to `text2` by dos batch.

Text1 like that;

```
20130701,xxxx,xxxx,xxx

20130702,yyyy,yyy,yyyyyyy
```

I want to copy only `"20130701"` line from `text1` to `text2`, using dos command. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

This will create text2.txt with any lines from text1.txt that start with 20130701

```
findstr "^20130701" <"text1.txt"  >"text2.txt"
```

Original answer below:

```
set text1=20130701,xxxx,xxxx,xxx

set text2=20130702,yyyy,yyy,yyyyyyy

set text3=%text1:~0,8%%text2:~8%

echo %text3%
```

Comment: I think I did not explain my issue correctly. I have a file which name is text1.txt and include some info in rows like;20130701,xxx,xxxx,xxxx   --20130702,zzzzz,zzzz,zzzzz-20130703,ttttt,ttttt so, I want get extract the row which start 20130701 to write another file like text2.txt